# Confused by angular firestore possibilities

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Can someone please enlighten me as I can't get the grasp on what this is all about using **Angular and Firestore**.

Started using **Google Firebase and tried to implement CRUD using Firestore**.

What is the *difference* between this library.

```
import { Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
...
this.coll = collection(this.firestore, 'user-services');

collectionData(this.coll, {
    idField: 'id'
  }).pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }))...
```

And the **other firestore library** used in the git repository in the documentation.. (https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/bea9d6774ce455d50363f9844ea48c32d6c37eb6/docs/firestore/collections.md)

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```

I think this is really weird that there is no straight line on which to use, if I try to use them both the first one stops working..

Can someone explain to me what's happening under the hood or provide some history / usage guide which one is newest / safest to use?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They changed a lot in version 9 so they provided a compatibility layer "@angular/fire/**compat**/firestore" to allow a smoother migration coming from firebase 8.

The import "@angular/fire/firestore" is the new tree shakeable version for a smaller bundle size.

In your case if it's brand new project you should not use the compatibility layer.

You can read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade